# ContourPlot performs extremely slow in equations

Tags: plotting, function-construction

I am trying to build a solution for an equation with Contourplot:

```
NN = 60;
n = 15;
ContourPlot[F[T, t] == 0, {T, -2, -1}, {t, -1, 1}]
```

Function F is generated from eigenvalues of two matrices, one of each depends on T and t:

```
F[T_, t_] :=  Module[{H = Table[0., {i, 1, NN}, {j, 1, NN}], eig1, eig0, i, j},
For[i = 1, i <= NN, i++, H[[i, i]] = -5];
For[i = 2, i <= NN, i += 2,
    H[[i, i - 1]] = T;
    H[[i - 1, i]] = T;
];
For[i = 3, i <= NN, i += 2,
    H[[i, i - 1]] = t;
    H[[i - 1, i]] = t;
];
H[[1, NN]] = t;
H[[NN, 1]] = t;
eig1 = Eigenvalues[H];

For[i = 2, i <= NN, i++,
    H[[i, i - 1]] =-1.;
    H[[i - 1, i]] = -1.;
];
H[[1, NN]] = -1;
H[[NN, 1]] = -1;
eig0 = Eigenvalues[H];

Sum[eig0[[l]] - eig1[[l]], {l, 1, n}]/NN]
```

While the function itself calculates almost instantly, the ContourPlot takes forever. At the same time, if I remove "==0" in the ContourPlot, and put "Contours->{0}", it works fast.

Can someone explain me what is going on here, and how should I use Mathematica for finding solutions to equations efficiently?

Comment: To avoid slow analytic evaluation use option `Evaluated -> False`, i.e.,  `ContourPlot[F[T, t] == 0, {T, -2, -1}, {t, -1, 1}, Evaluated -> False]`

Comment: Your code is inefficient. For example, you initialize `H` to be all zeroes then set the main diagonal to `-5`. You can do this more simply with `H = -5  IdentityMatrix[NN]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Ah, nice. 'Evaluated -> False' worked. Thanks for the code improvement as well.